# iphone : How to make an array with objects from other arrays

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have three NSMutabelArrays, each contain about ten strings, for example:

```
    1stArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",nil];

    2ndArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",nil];

    3rdArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",nil];
```

Now I want to make a 4th NSMutabelArrays with first 2 objects of those 3 NSMutableArray.
for example I want a 4th array like this:

```
4thArray = [@"a",@"b",@"j",@"k",@"q",@"r"]
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), [NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: do no declear your array names with 1st, 2nd, 3rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a code like this

```
int numElements = 2;
int numArrays = 3;

NSMutableArray * 4thArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int arrays = 0; arrays < numArrays; arrays++) {
    for (int count = 0; count < numElements; count++) {
        switch (arrays) {
            case 0:
                [4thArray addObject:[1stArray objectAtIndex:count]];
                break;
            case 1:
                [4thArray addObject:[2ndArray objectAtIndex:count]];
                break;
            case 2:
                [4thArray addObject:[3rdArray objectAtIndex:count]];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be better solved using an array of arrays, or possibly a combination of arrays and dictionaries, depending on what you're trying to achieve.  The answer to your question is trivial, so I'll point you to the [NSArray Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for that, but you probably want to consider a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",nil];
    NSMutableArray *secArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",nil];
   NSMutableArray *thrdArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"q",@"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",nil];

    NSMutableArray *fourthArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[firstArray objectAtIndex:0],[firstArray objectAtIndex:1], [secArray objectAtIndex:0],[secArray objectAtIndex:1], [thrdArray objectAtIndex:0],[thrdArray objectAtIndex:1],nil];
    NSLog(@"%d", fourthArr.count);
```

Comment: set a breakpoint, you will see all your desired elements in fourth array